# How to disable brackets concealment vimtex?

Tags: vim, vim-latex

Brackets `\[` and `\]` are only shown when my cursor hovering over them. I tried to use `let g:vimtex_syntax_conceal_default = 0` and `set conceallevel=0`, but it still not working.

[image: vim example]

Answer (score 1):

I applied the setting `set conceallevel=0` and restarted the document and everything worked out!